# How to store video url, id taken from database one after the other and display recently added one?

Tags: php, mysql

code given can only displays recently added youtube video image and category of the video . but when i add need data into the database the old image and category will be replaced by the new image and category. but what i need is to store the previous displayed image and category with in the page along with recently added

```
  <a target='_blank' href='updatespot-information.php?ide=<?php echo"$lastid"; ?>'>
    <img style='width:100%; min-height:115px; padding:0px; border:#ccc solid 1px;' src='http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/<?php echo"$r"; ?>/0.jpg'>
  </a>

 <b id='viewfont'>Category: </b>
    <a target='_blank' href='updatespot-information-category.php?ide=Animation Videos'>Animation Videos</a>
```

[my webpage is mostly similar to the link](http://updatespot.com/videos-upload.php)

Comment: What is the specific problem or question? Suggest reading [ask]

Comment: actually I have a web page which stores youtube video url ,category of the video into MySQL database. now I need to display the url id and category of the video one after the other based on id in an order. And  recently added video url and the category  need to display above the previous displayed ids and categories

Comment: That doesn't explain a code related problem or question. You already stated that in the initial post and showed us some html with no explanation of what needs to be done to that html

Comment: I have a web page which stores youtube video url ,category of the video into MySQL database. now I need to display the url id and category of the video one after the other based on id in an order. And recently added video url and the category need to display above the previous displayed ids and categories

Comment: You keep outlining goals not specific code related problems achieving those goals. Nobody can help without understanding what your problem is and asking specific question(s) related to that problem

Comment: share your database structure

Comment: code given  can only displays recently added youtube video image and category of the video . but when i add need data into the database the old image and category will be replaced by the new image and category. but what i need is to store the previous displayed image and category with in the page along with recently added

Comment: database contains single table with id, youtube url ,category, as columns